# Redirect Host OS Nginx to Docker Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, express, nginx, gitlab

I have a Angular app developed using docker as a series of services. I have a mongodb service, an express API and an Nginx container that serves the built angular application. This works fine on my laptop for testing. However, the server i'm  trying to deploy to has GitLab installed as well which has Nginx bundled in. I have managed to follow the GitLab instructions to add a custom rule to Nginx.

Is it possible to redirect the requests from the host OS Nginx (Gitlab one) to the Nginx container so the app can be served. I have tried serving the angular application from the host Nginx but it cant communicate with my express API and it doesn't render correctly as the file paths are messed up.

I have the domain example.com which currently defaults to gitlab and example.com/gitlab which obviously goes direct to gitlab. I want to set it so that example.com/myapp as you can guess, goes to my application.

**UPDATE**

The following is the Nginx configuration that i have running on the server, it should redirect me to the angular app in docker when i got to example.com/testing. I have kind of got it doing it but in Chrome's console i get '**http://example.com/assets/js/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**'.
If i copy the link into a new tab and change it to http://example.com/testing/assets/js/test.js it still doesn't work.

```
upstream dockerangularsite {
 server localhost:4200;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name git-srv.wlv.ac.uk;
  server_tokens off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  location /testing {
     proxy_pass http://dockerangularsite;
  }
}
```

This is the Nginx configuration in the docker container:

```
server {
  listen 4200;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ .index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**Further Update**

I seem to have solved the problem by adding the following to the host nginx configuration and the baseHref suggestion.

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
   proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

However, the Gitlab server has now been updated/configured to use SSL and i'm currently trying to get it working again using HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I have similar scenario. Look for nginx reverse proxy. If you have api on another host or port you need to create a path for it too.

Comment: What have you tryied so far, can you share your nginx.conf file ?

Comment: i have posted the info above :)

Comment: Maybe you need to build with `ng build --base-href /testing/`. I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried to build with the command suggested by Leonardo? It seems to me that the problem is that your angular application does not know that all its URLs start with `/testing/` prefix.

Comment: I tried the --base-href suggestion and it worked in combination with a slight tweak to my nginx configuration. Trying to get SSL sorted now :(

Answer (score -1):

do you already expose/setting port? of the docker service?
search google how to bind port 4200 of docker to localhost,

please input the result of `netstat -ntlp` too...

I think here is the correct place of provide nginx config above

```
upstream dockerangularsite {
 server localhost:4200;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name git-srv.wlv.ac.uk;
  server_tokens off;

  location /testing {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass http://dockerangularsite;
  }
}
```

for docker nginx

```
server {
  listen 4200;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```